# How to edit my video with iMoviewithout losing original dimensions

Tags: imovie

This may be the simplest question because I am very new in video editing. Basically I have a video of 640x1080 dimension (I recorded iPhone 6 screen with QuickTime). To I just want to add some text and sound to it. I know how to do the jobs; however, the problem is, when I created a new project in iMovie, I can only choose project of size 4:3 or 16:9. After importing, editing my video, and exporting, I will have a video with black borders at 2 sides. How can I preserve the original dimension?

Comment: 1080x640 does not match with 4:3 or 16:9. If there is no option to set a custom ratio, (27:16 in your case), try another tool or crop the video, depends on what do you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

iMovie does not support any aspect ratios besides 4:3 and 16:9.